# Change FontWeight of specific row of DevExpress GridControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to Change the FontWeight of a specific row to bold. So i have a DataTable (MyDataTable):

```
Name     Location
-------------------
Mark     New-York
Julian   Paris
Donald   Moscow
```

which i bind to a DevExpress GridControl

```
<dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataTable}">
```

Now i would like to Change the FontWeight of the row where the Name is 'Julian'. How can i do this?

I thought using a DataTrigger like:

```
 <dxg:GridControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type dxg:GridRow}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyDataTable.Columns[0]}" Value="Name">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </dxg:GridControl.Resources>
```

but this is not working. I tried several other Options, but did not find a working solution. Can someone please guide me in the right direction? I would very much prefer to do it directly in xaml and not in code behind, if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [FormatConditions Property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridTableView_FormatConditionstopic) to format row or cell with condition

```
<dxg:TableView.FormatConditions> <dxg:FormatCondition Expression="[Name] = 'Julian'" FieldName="Name" />
```

**EDIT:**

If you want formatting in code - [Formatting in Code](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument114001)

Comment: Thx. Like  '<dxg:TableView.FormatConditions>
                        <dxg:FormatCondition Expression="[Name]" FieldName="Julian" />
' ? What to put in Expression and FieldName?